# Using async await C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, async-await

I have started using Xamarin recently and I am quite new to c#. I want to create an asynchronous HTTP request, so I started using async and await with HttpWebRequest. But I don't get an asynchronous called, the UI is getting block. This is the code I'm testing. I have two implementation the RequestCitas() should be asynchronous and the SRequestCitas() is synchronous, what is wrong?.

```
namespace mc
{
[Activity (Label = "mc", MainLauncher = true, Theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{

    List<Cita> citas;
    CitaAdapter adapter;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        citas = new List<Cita> ();
        adapter = new CitaAdapter (this, citas);
        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.main_citas);
        listView.Adapter = adapter;

        var c1 = new Cita (0, "ernesto", "De los Santos", "19/2/14", "19/2/14", "09:28", "10:45");
        var c2 = new Cita (1, "ernesto", "De los Santos", "19/2/14", "19/2/14", "09:28", "10:45");
        var c3 = new Cita (2, "ernesto", "De los Santos", "19/2/14", "19/2/14", "09:28", "10:45");
        var c4 = new Cita (3, "ernesto", "De los Santos", "19/2/14", "19/2/14", "09:28", "10:45");
        var c5 = new Cita (4, "ernesto", "De los Santos", "19/2/14", "19/2/14", "09:28", "10:45");

        citas.Add (c1);
        citas.Add (c2);
        citas.Add (c3);
        citas.Add (c4);
        citas.Add (c5);

        Console.WriteLine ("Notificando al adaptador");
        adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();

        string result;

        FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button1).Click += async (sender, e) => {
            result =  await RequestCitas ();
        };
        FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button2).Click += delegate {
            result = SRequestCitas ();
        };
    }

    private async Task<string>  RequestCitas ()
    {

        // var url = "http://192.168.1.126:8081";
        var url = "http://192.168.1.124";
        //var method = "/citas/get";
        var method = "";

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding ();
        byte[] parametros = encoding.GetBytes ("usersID=97");

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url + method);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = parametros.Length;

        var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        dataStream.Write (parametros, 0, parametros.Length);
        dataStream.Close ();

        string str = ""; 

        Task<WebResponse> task = request.GetResponseAsync ();

        WebResponse newResponse = await task;

        var responseStream = newResponse.GetResponseStream ();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader (responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding ("utf-8"));
        char[] read = new Char[256];
        int count = streamReader.Read (read, 0, 256);

        while (count > 0) {
            str += new string (read, 0, count);
            count = streamReader.Read (read, 0, 256);
        }
        responseStream.Close ();

        return str;
    }


    private string SRequestCitas ()
    {

        var url = "http://192.168.1.126:8081";
        var method = "/citas/get";

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding ();
        byte[] parametros = encoding.GetBytes ("usersID=97");

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (url + method);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = parametros.Length;

        var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream ();
        dataStream.Write (parametros, 0, parametros.Length);
        dataStream.Close ();

        string str = ""; 

        HttpWebResponse newResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

        var responseStream = newResponse.GetResponseStream ();
        var streamReader = new StreamReader (responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding ("utf-8"));
        char[] read = new Char[256];
        int count = streamReader.Read (read, 0, 256);

        while (count > 0) {
            str += new string (read, 0, count);
            count = streamReader.Read (read, 0, 256);
        }
        responseStream.Close ();

        return str;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Does your code compile? You're using `await` inside a non async void method. Also, it look like your `while` loop is whats blocking your UI, not the awaited task

Answer (score 0):

You're getting response using an `async` method, but you're reading the stream using synchronous stream operations. Try using `streamReader.ReadAsync` instead.

Or, if you're feeling ambitious, you could try replacing your whole `while` loop altogether and use:

```
var str = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
```

On a side note, `StreamReader` implements `IDisposable` and you're not properly disposing of the instance when you're done with it. You could be leaking native resources.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a method which uses the `await` keyword, it has to me be marked as `async` for the compiler to allow the use of the keyword. More over, you should follow the guidelines and end your method with the Async prefix

Your `async` method is reading synchronously from the from the `StreamReader` which is causing your UI to block.

Here's a async implementation using [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx):

```
private async Task<string> RequestCitasAsync()
{
    var url = "http://192.168.1.126:8081/citas/get";
    byte[] parametros = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("usersID=97");

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new ByteArrayContent(parametros));

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```